# Method connect() from type PircBotX not visible

Tags: java

I am trying to create a bot using PircBotX, however I am unable to even get started making it. Using just the basic example code, I am unable to get the `connect()` method to work, it always give the error at compile mentioned in the title. Here is the code I am using:

```
import org.pircbotx.Configuration;
import org.pircbotx.PircBotX;

public class MyBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
        .setName("PircBotX") //Set the nick of the bot. CHANGE IN YOUR CODE
        .setLogin("LQ") //login part of hostmask, eg name:login@host
        .setAutoNickChange(true) //Automatically change nick when the current one is in use
        .setCapEnabled(true) //Enable CAP features
        .setServerHostname("irc.freenode.net")
        .addAutoJoinChannel("#pircbotx") //Join the official #pircbotx channel
        .buildConfiguration();
        PircBotX bot = new PircBotX(configuration);

        //Connect to server
        try {
            bot.connect();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs with the line `bot.connect();`

PircBotX can be found at its Google Code page: https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/

Comment: That could mean that the method `connect()` is not suppose to be called from you, hence it being not visible, is there another method that is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [docs](http://site.pircbotx.googlecode.com/hg-history/2.0.1/apidocs/index.html), there is a method called `startBot()`, should that be used instead?

`void     startBot()     Start the bot by connecting to the server.`

```
import org.pircbotx.Configuration;
import org.pircbotx.PircBotX;

public class MyBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
        .setName("PircBotX") //Set the nick of the bot. CHANGE IN YOUR CODE
        .setLogin("LQ") //login part of hostmask, eg name:login@host
        .setAutoNickChange(true) //Automatically change nick when the current one is in use
        .setCapEnabled(true) //Enable CAP features
        .setServerHostname("irc.freenode.net")
        .addAutoJoinChannel("#pircbotx") //Join the official #pircbotx channel
        .buildConfiguration();
        PircBotX bot = new PircBotX(configuration);

        //Connect to server
        try {
            //bot.connect();
            bot.startBot();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't seem to work. While I could access that method, it did not connect to the server as I needed.

Comment: Was there an error that was thrown? Are you sure that you have the right configuration?